# Should we use "late" for Model to fix safety-null error

Tags: flutter, dart, model

```
class ItemModel {

late int _page;
  late int _total_results;
  late int _total_pages;
  late List<_Result> _results = [];

  ItemModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    // debugPrint(parsedJson['results'].length);
    _page = parsedJson['page'];
    _total_results = parsedJson['total_results'];
    _total_pages = parsedJson['total_pages'];
    List<_Result> temp = [];
    for (int i = 0; i < parsedJson['results'].length; i++) {
      _Result result = _Result(parsedJson['results'][i]);
      temp.add(result);
    }
    _results = temp;
  }

  List<_Result> get results => _results;

  int get total_pages => _total_pages;

  int get total_results => _total_results;

  int get page => _page;
}
```

Can I use **late** to fix ***Non-nullable instance field '_page' must be initialized.
Try adding an initializer expression, or add a field initializer in this constructor, or mark it "late"?*** error.

Or I can use **?**

```
int? _page;
```

For ? : i get this error ***A value of type 'int?' can't be returned from the function 'page' because it has a return type of 'int'***

Which would be better?

Thanks for your reply!

Comment: while using the model most developers prefer to use? this instead of late keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally make a constructor for your object and make your JSON parsing a factory constructor returning an instance of your class. By doing so, we can skip the use of `late` variables:

```dart
class ItemModel {
  final int page;
  final int total_results;
  final int total_pages;
  final List<_Result> results;

  const ItemModel({
    required this.page,
    required this.total_results,
    required this.total_pages,
    required this.results,
  });

  factory ItemModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) => ItemModel(
        page: parsedJson['page'] as int,
        total_results: parsedJson['total_results'] as int,
        total_pages: parsedJson['total_pages'] as int,
        results: [
          for (var i = 0; i < parsedJson['results'].length; i++)
            _Result(parsedJson['results'][i])
        ],
      );
}
```

Of if you still wants your getters:

```dart
class ItemModel {
  final int _page;
  final int _total_results;
  final int _total_pages;
  final List<_Result> _results;

  const ItemModel({
    required int page,
    required int total_results,
    required int total_pages,
    required List<_Result> results,
  })  : _page = page,
        _total_results = total_results,
        _total_pages = total_pages,
        _results = results;

  factory ItemModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) => ItemModel(
        page: parsedJson['page'] as int,
        total_results: parsedJson['total_results'] as int,
        total_pages: parsedJson['total_pages'] as int,
        results: [
          for (var i = 0; i < parsedJson['results'].length; i++)
            _Result(parsedJson['results'][i])
        ],
      );

  List<_Result> get results => _results;
  int get total_pages => _total_pages;
  int get total_results => _total_results;
  int get page => _page;
}
```

Comment: how do use _ operator, (ex: final int _page;). I really want to use getter functions for this Class. Thank you!

Comment: Well, if you just want to just have a getter published to the public, you can use `final`. But you can also just rename all the variables in my example to the ones you had before and reintroduce the getters. I have added an example of how to have them. We need to change the constructor a little since we are not allowed to have private names as named parameters. :)